# Why is this particular code for comparing arraylists not working?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two different arraylists that I want to compare - specifically to check if a certain element of list1 exists in list2.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    if (list2.contains(list1.get(i))) {
        System.out.println ("match");
    }
}
```

Basically I am looping through list1 - and checking if list2 contains element from list1. This if statement is however not being executed - and no values are null.

The logic and code seems OK to me. What is wrong?

Comment: You're printing an empty string `""`, print `list1.get(i)` maybe ? And what object does your list contain ? You have to implement `equals()` method on your object.

Comment: Is it the exact same object in the list? i.e. should `equals` be true? How do you know it's not working? debugging or println output (as your println will only return a carriage return.

Comment: who says there is an actual match? {"fred","bob", "billy"} and {"dora","cindy","agnes"} won't give a match either, still, the if statement will have run.

Comment: What types of object do the lists contain? Do they correctly implement 'equals()'?

Comment: Provided informations insufficient to provide an answer. what are the elements in those two lists.?

Comment: They contain Strings. list1 contains the string "job" and list2 contains the string "job", but the equals/if statement is not being executed.

Comment: @SandeepShah check this out.. https://ideone.com/2sNNZ0

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Weird. I did the exact same thing. Thank you.

Comment: @SandeepShah post your full code here. We will notify the issue in your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the intersection between two lists, the better approach would be to use `retainAll` method. Suppose you have two lists such that:

```
List<String> list1 = asList("Martin", "Eric", "Kent");
List<String> list2 = asList("Kent", "Josh", "Eric");
```

The following list will hold the intersection between the two:

```
List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
intersection.retainAll(list2);
```

After calling `retainsAll`, intersection will only contains `Kent` and `Eric`.

Comment: Its certainly the better approach, but it doesn't answer the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

(This is really a comment. Unfortunately, SE has a coincidental coupling between comment vs. answer and formatting options.)

Here is an example of a complete program that tests your code, but works. For clarity, I printed a non-empty string on match. I suggest modifying it by replacing the lists with the failing case. If it fails, post the complete program.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listA = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "job" });
    List<String> listB = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "bbb", "job" });
    System.out.println("One match");
    matcher(listA, listB);
  }

  public static void matcher(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
      if (list2.contains(list1.get(i))) {
        System.out.println("Found one.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution but I don't think here describe the issue or the solution for it..

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera No, it is not a solution. It is a comment suggesting the sort of thing the OP needs to post to get a solution.

Comment: An alternative to posting a non-answer may be to paste the code into some online-shareable snippet host for Java code to include with your comment.

Comment: @CubeJockey Personally, I don't follow links from SE unless I am sure I trust the person posting the link. Code on the page is more likely to be seen. Maybe one day SE will realize that the formatting limitations of comments make no sense, and provide a proper way to post things like this. Until then, I post them as answers, with an indication is is really a comment, and sometimes lose a few reputation points, which I don't need anyway.